# PHP: Error handling for errors within custom error handling method

Tags: php

I have created a common custom error handler for all my php webservices, in that error handler i'm sending a mail, thus no error msg is shown to my users.

My ques is what if some error occurs while sending mail, how to handle it, I don't want any php error msg to be shown to my users.

P.S:- I have tried registering another custom error handler without mailing code , but it seems not to be working.

Answer (score 0):

You can use structure try{}catch() for catch exception and handle error as:

```
try{
   //Your send mail function in here
}catch(\Exception $e){
    var_dump($e->getMessage());
    //Write log to file
}
```

Comment: I have already used try/catch but afaik it won't be able to handle errors, it is for exceptions